# MATLAB imagesc command not working for non-evenly spaced y-axis values

Tags: image, matlab, plot

Ok, so this is starting to get very frustrating.

I have the following code: ([scannedResponse](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4724281/scannedResponse.mat), [thetaAxis](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4724281/thetaAxis.mat) given here).

```
clear all
load scannedResponse
load thetaAxis
figure(1); clf(1);
pcolor(1:size(scannedResponse,2), thetaAxis, scannedResponse); shading interp; 
figure(2); clf(2);
imagesc(1:s.N.Lsnaps, (thetaAxis),  scannedResponse);
```

So I get two images. One made with pcolor, and one made with imagesc. The pcolor image is correct, because the y-axis is correct, and the lines are where they are supposed to be. The imagesc is wrong, because the y-axis is wrong, and the lines are not where they are supposed to be.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the lines of the imagesc image do not agree with the lines of the pcolor image. I cannot seem to get the imagesc y-axis to agree with the pcolor y-axis, and thus give me a similar plot. How do I go about doing that?

P.S. I have already tried the full gamut of flipping the y-axis for imagesc, using the `set(gca,'Ydir', 'normal')` command, etc etc to no avail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that thetaAxis contains non-equally spaced values. `pcolor` can deal with that, `imagesc` can't. A solution is to interpolate your data to get them on an equally spaced grid:

```
% determine interpolation grid: from min to max in equal steps
intpoints = linspace(min(thetaAxis), max(thetaAxis), numel(thetaAxis));
% interpolate the data to fit the new "axis"
int = interp1(thetaAxis', scannedResponse, intpoints);
% plot the interpolated data  using the new "axis"
imagesc(1:size(scannedResponse,2), intpoints, int)
% revert the direction of the y axis
axis xy
```

Except for the implicit smoothing that pcolor appears to do, this plot looks identical to the one using `pcolor(1:size(scannedResponse,2), thetaAxis, scannedResponse); shading interp`.

Comment: Ah! Fantastic A Donda. Yes, it seems that the non-equally spaced values were the problem. So question, you are interpolating, but not changing the length of the thetaAxis vector yes? You are just finding NEW values of scannedResponse at NEW evenly spaced values of thetaVec correct?

Comment: Right, I made it so that the numer of values stays the same. Of course that's not necessarily optimal; alternatively you could choose the spacing such that it corresponds to the smallest spacing in your original "axis".

Comment: One last question, I am trying to use the rot90 command to rotate the image counterclockwise, but the time-axis, (the one going from 1 to 100) is not screwed up... how would I fix that? Thanks so much again.

Comment: With the interpolated image, there should not be a problem rotating it. But are you sure you want to do that? If you want to exchange the axes, transposition `'` would be the way to go.

Comment: What I mean is, I just want to use rot90(myImage). Of course, the time axis previously on the x-axis, is now on the y-axis. The problem is that it is going from 100 to 1, and not from 1 to 100. How do I flip it? I cant seem to do it.

Comment: That's exactly why I wouldn't use rotation, but transposition. This way the two axes are exchanged, but not reversed. To put it differently, rot90 = transposition + flipping, or transposition = rot90 - flipping. If you really want to use rot90 and then flip, you can do it either graphically, by setting the 'XDir' and/or 'YDir' axes properties accordingly, or by applying `flipud` and/or `fliplr` to the image data.