# MATLAB Heat Maps scaled to an axis

Tags: matlab

I've got some data corresponding discrete values to temperature

I want to create a heat map (more like a heat bar I guess) where everything from 0 - A is one temperature, A - B is another, B - C is another, etc.

I've tried HeatMap and imagesc, but neither of these are scaling to the axis.

Both of them are in the form of:

```
h = [0, 13, 17, 22, 25, 30, 40];
temp = [3000, 2200, 2100, 1900, 1800, 1700, 1600]
w = 20;
colormap(hot);
HeatMap(temp,'RowLabels',h);
```

or

```
imagesc(temp, 'XData', h);
```

or

```
HeatMap(h,w,temp); % Not sure if I formatted this right
```

I know that RowLabels and YData only rename the labels on the axis, but I can't get my head around any other method of scaling them. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about `HeatMap`, but `imagesc` does [not handle non-equally spaced coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19084037/2056067). Instead you can use `pcolor(X, Y, C)`:

```
pcolor([h 50], [0 1], [temp 0 ; temp 0])
shading flat
```

[image: scaled heatmap]

As you state in your question, the values of `temp` apply *between* two values of `h`, which means that you need one value more in `h` than in `temp` to achieve what you want. I just added the value 50, I'm not sure whether this is the right choice for you.

On the other hand, `pcolor` associates values of `C` with edges (not intervals), in order to be able to interpolate the `C`-values between the edges. `shading flat` tells it to use the `C`-value of the lower edge for the whole interval, but still you need one value more in `temp`, which is then simply ignored – I used 0. The reference to edges holds for both dimensions, which is why `C` needs to have at least two elements along each dimension. Here I just replicated the data in the vertical direction, `[temp 0 ; zeros(size(temp)) 0]` would work as well.